# Google Analytics :report on total number of visitor who spends more than 4 sec time on a page

Tags: google-analytics

How can I generate a report on Google Analytics console with the following criteria:

**Total no of visitor** 1.on a page url
                        2.on a specific day
                        3.**who spent more than 4 sec on that page.**

GA has parameter **time on page** but it gives total time on that page not the time per visitor.**So is it possible to filter the total no of visitor who spends more that 4 sec on that page?**

Please suggest.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

setting the days period first,
the goes to content section on GA left side panel, and click all content, then search the page name you want to check like index.aspx.  information will displayed how many visitor on that page in the chosen period. and average staying time.

cheers

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also need to get total number of visitor per page who spends more than 4 sec on that page.Please suggest.

Comment: have a look on this: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=16858c02144491ee&hl=en